# How do I measure the UDP packet size I just received?

Tags: java, sockets, udp

I am learning to program UDP a bit. How would I get the size of a packet I receive from a UDP server?

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[1000];
DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length);
datagramSocket.receive(packet);
buffer = packet.getData();
```

In the above code snippet, I am declaring the buffer size as 1000 bytes. So it is obvious that I cannot get the size by simply calling `buffer.length` which will return 1000 in any case.

Can someone please tell me if there is a way to do it?

Comment: Seriously dude, did you read the javadoc before asking this question?  And if not, why not?

Answer (score 3):

You could use the [getLength()](http://download.java.net/jdk7/archive/b123/docs/api/java/net/DatagramPacket.html#getLength()) method in DatagramPacket, such as `packet.getLength()` to be able to get the packet size.